# Trouble setting up DHCP with WRN2000v2 and GS108 network switch

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have the  [GS108](http://kb.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/2439) Netgear 8 port Gigabit network switch and the [WRN2000v2](http://kb.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/12168) Netgear wireless router. The problem I am having is that anything conneted through the Gigabit switch is not being assigned an IP address through DHCP. If I connect directly to the router it will assign an IP. I originally had a Linksys Wireless G router that used these same switches, but recently swapped it out, since I was having problems with the wireless. I decided to go with the Netgear since I had been pleased with the Gigabit switch I had purchased, and figured it would be the least headache to swap in.

So here is what I know:

- the lights between the router and the gigabit switch indicate a 100MB connection (1 light)
- the lights between the laptop and the gigabit switch indicate a gigabit connection (2 lights)
- Tried assigning a static ip to the laptop, and that did not work either
- Swapped out cables, still no change
- Connected laptop wired directly to the router(it assigns the ip address)
- Connected laptop to gigabit switch that is connected to the router(it does not assign an ip address)
- Double checked the router configuration page, and DHCP is turned on

So I figure I am missing something, and hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried pinging the router from the laptop?

Comment: What does "tried assigning a static IP to the laptop" mean exactly?  Are you sure you have a solid connection between the laptop and the router through the switch?  If you put two computers on the Gigabit network with static IPs can they communicate?

Comment: Sounds like it should work.  The switch doesn't work on any of the 4 ports on the router?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't checked back. I actually figured it out just now. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more troubleshooting I found the problem. I needed a crossover cable between the router and the switch. Apparently the **OLD Linksys router** that worked had some type of automatic feature that did this, while the **NEW Netgear router** did not have this feature.

So in assuming things get better over time, I assumed the Netgear router, that was probably made a good two years after the Linksys router would have the same feature. I was wrong, and wasted a good bit of time in figuring this out. I have basic networking knowledge, and new that you used to always have to use a crossover cable between switches, but glossed over it since the old one worked with standard cables. Lesson learned.

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  If I understand auto-MDIX correctly, only 1 of the connecting devices needs it, and the switch has it.  Something else is afoot.

Comment: All I know is that once I swapped out the standard ethernet cable to a crossover cable it worked correctly. So I am happy. It did seem weird to me also though. Just for the record I did try multiple ethernet cables before the crossover, so I am fairly certain that it was not a bad cable.